# Neo4j, Match Relationship where persons commenting on the same posts

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have some sample data that consists of 2x node types; PERSONS and POSTS with a relationship of COMMENTED_ON. I am able to visualise in Neo4J all the Persons/Posts and whos commented on what. However i am wanting to do something more complex and thats to isolate people who are commenting on the same posts.

John and Tim comment on POST1
Sarah comment on POST2
John and Tim comment on POST3
John and Sarah comment on POST4

In the above example John and Tim are commenting on the same videos, as you can see both of them have commented on POST1+POST3

Im wanting to do this to try and identify people who might know each by means of they are commenting on the same posts.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:
In this pattern you represent 2 people commenting on the same course.

Then count the frequency and list results ordered by highest frequency.

```
MATCH (p1:Person)-[:COMMENTED_ON]->(post)<-[:COMMENTED_ON]-(p2:Person)
WITH p1,p2, count(post) as freq
ORDER BY freq DESC LIMIT 100
RETURN p1.name,p2.name, freq
```

Answer (score 0):

Match each person commenting the same post. This will will be a pair of person.
Collect all posts and collect each name (you need to do this in 2 steps).
Unwind means to expand the collected person names into a rows/sequence.
Sort the result by posts (ORDER by).
Then collect (again) the person names (to put them in one list).
Return only the first item (n[0]) in the person list

```
MATCH (n1:Person)-[: COMMENTED_ON]->(post) <- [: COMMENTED_ON] - (n2: Person)
WITH n1,n2, collect(post.name) as posts
WITH collect([n1.name, n2.name]) as coln, posts
UNWIND coln as n 
WITH n , posts ORDER by posts 
WITH collect (n) as n,  posts
RETURN  n[0] as Person, posts as Post
```

Result:

[image]